# Android: how to read system setting for vibration on key presses

Tags: android

How can I programmatically read the system setting for the virtual keyboard? I want my app buttons to behave like it is set in the system settings for the virtual keyboard (beep, vibrate or nothing).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `performHapticFeedback` for it. Do not forget to enable it for your views in layout xml.

[View.performHapticFeedback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performHapticFeedback%28int,%20int%29)

Use stock [Haptic feedback](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=693B87150B6AE2B3442695D66936A30D?recipeId=1242)